# How to turn unwanted string values into NaNs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I struggle with one task. I have imported an unclean dataframe and some columns that are supposed to have only float values also have strings which is corrupting my data and not allowing me to perform a regression.

If I have a dataframe `X` and `"investment_rounds"` column with mixed data types.

I want something like

```
np.where(X["investment_rounds"] == np.dtype.str, np.nan, X)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They key here is the `errors='coerce'` parameter of `to_numeric`

Per the [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) it will replace any value which cannot be converted with `NaN`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'investment_rounds':['1.0','2.0','bad','data','3.0']})
df['investment_rounds'] = pd.to_numeric(df['investment_rounds'], errors='coerce')
```

Output

```
    investment_rounds
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   3.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped.

Can you do the same for the whole dataframe?  Currently, I just used the for loop. I would have upvoted but don't have the reputation yet :)

Comment: If you had columns A, B, C and you wanted to convert them all at the same time `df[['A','B','C']] = df[['A','B','C'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`